# how to keep the validation errors intact while submitting form to different route in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to submit the form to route `form/submit` from my `contact` route. What i need is validation errors to show on the current route i.e. `contact` and not on `form/submit`

```php
========= contact view =========
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('form/submit'); ?>
<?php echo form_input(array(
      'type'          => 'email',
      'name'          => 'yourEmail',
      'required'      => 'true'
)); ?>
<input type="submit">


====== 'routes' =======
$route['form/submit']['POST'] = 'form/submit';
```

here is the issue i want to keep the url same if there are errors, if instead of loading view if i redirect i lose my error messages i am trying not to use sessions to store the error messages.

```php
======= 'controllers' =======

public function submit()
    {
      $this->load->helper('form');
      $this->load->library('form_validation');


      $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|email');

      if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
      {

      $this->load->view('contact');
      }
      else
      {
          $this->prison_model->set_prison();
          $this->load->view('success');
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using ajax for form submissions.

if you don't want to use ajax then create a library class of **Prison** without inheriting codeignitor class.

pass homepage url to open_multipart().
By doing this all of the form submission info will be passed to home controller, in that create object of Prison & call create().
after that load any views in home controller.

You should use **Prison** class only for processing.

Comment: because i dont want to